# How to insert the rdd data into a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Please find below the psuedocode:

## source dataframe with 5 columns

## creating a target dataframe with schema(6 columns)

For item in source_dataframe:
    #adding a column to the list buy checking item.coulmn2
    list = [item.column1,item.column2,newcolumn]
    #creating an rdd out of this list
    #now i need to add this rdd to a target dataframe?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could definately explain your question a bit more in detail or give some sample code. I'm interested how others will solve that. My proposed solution is this one:

```py
df = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (134, "2016-07-02 12:01:40"), 
        (134, "2016-07-02 12:21:23"),
        (125, "2016-07-02 13:22:56"), 
        (125, "2016-07-02 13:27:07")
        ]).toDF(["itemid", "timestamp"])
)

rdd = df.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], 10))
df2 = rdd.toDF(["itemid", "timestamp", "newCol"])

df3 = df.join(df2, df.itemid == df2.itemid and df.timestamp == df2.timestamp, "inner").drop(df2.itemid).drop(df2.timestamp)
```

I'm converting the RDD to a Dataframe. Afterwards I join both Dataframes, which duplicates some columns. So finally I drop those duplicated columns.

Comment: Thank you!!! my scenario is a bit complicated, but this solved the issue.
For now on, I will put the question with more detail.